# use macros for arguments

Tags: c, macros, wrapper, readability

I am trying to create a macro wrapper around a function so I could make the code more intuitive on reading. Something like instead of calling **send_message_to_destination(m, d)** to write **send(m)to(d)**.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void send_data_to(int data, int dest)
{
    printf("Send %d to %d\n", data, dest);
}


#define send(data)to(destination) send_data_to(data, destination) 

int main() {

    int data = 5;
    int dest = 10;

    send(data)to(dest);
}
```

It is possible to do so?
Do you think this would makes the code more readable or intuitive ?

Comment: It's rare for macros to make code more intuitive, if you are using them to invent a language.

Comment: This is in fact less intuitive for any C programmer. Don't try to change the grammar of C using whatever obscure way. If you don't want to use C syntax, a different  language might better suit you. If there is none, write your own, but don't try this with macros.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, but due to my not so good English, I misexpressed myself. I wanted a form of writing the code that sounds more like natural language and I want to use this in c++. I personally think it is nicer to call communicator.send(message1)to(server1) than communicator.send(mesage1, server1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the comments (not a good idea), however, you can use something like this.  Remember the pre-processor just does a text replace with your macros.

```
#define to(destination) destination)
#define send(data) send_data_to(data,
```

Answer (score 0):

No there is no such way to do so with MACROS